# VLANs, Subnets and a sensitive database server

Tags: network, appsec, vlans

I have a sensitive database, and two categories of employees Category A and Category B. Category A does not require access to the sensitive database while category B does require access to the database.

Initially I was thinking let's simply create 3 VLANs.

Vlan - 1 - Category A

Vlan - 2 - Category B

Vlan - 3 - Sensitive database

But this has an issue: Category B cannot communicate with the sensitive Database, because VLANs preclude VLAN 1 talking to VLAN - X. So, lets introduce a Subnet.

Place the sensitive database into a subnet and add a router. At the router, allow VLAN 2 to communicate with the subnet where the database exists, and tell the router to not allow VLAN 1 to communicate with the subnet where the database exists.

Question:  Does this achieve the objective of allowing Category B to communicate with the database and preventing category A from communicating with the Database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the switchs ports of your database in trunk mode and allow the vlan B and "sensitive database" and exclude vlan A of this trunk.

**Edit**

If yours vlans are on differents subnets you could allow the vlan Database with the VLAN B and not the A by using ACL in yours switchs L3.

Comment: Ok, so you are suggesting staying with the 3 VLANs and not introducing a subnet ? What would be considered industry best practices in this sceanrio ?

Comment: It depends if yours vlans are on the same subnet. It's preferred to have vlan by subnet and configure  acl to allow traffic with B and database and forbid vlanA. Moreover, you could configure the ports of yours switchs in the correct vlan.